# Why is this domain wrong?

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

I was trying to integrate:

$$\iiint_D x\ dx\,dy\,dz$$

where $D$ is limited by $x=4y^2+4z^2$ and $x=4$.

I have managed to find the answer by converting the domain to cylindrical coordinates, using:

$$z = r \sin(\theta)$$
$$y = r \cos(\theta)$$
$$x = x$$

and the domain:

$$D=\{(\theta,r,x):0<\theta<2\pi,0<r<\sqrt{\frac x4},0<x<4\} $$

Integrating over this domain, I got the right answer which is:

$$\iiint_D x\ dx\,dy\,dz=\frac {16\pi}{3}$$

However, this was not my first choice for a domain. I first tried:

$$B=\{(\theta,r,x):0<\theta<2\pi,0<r<1,0<x<4r^2\}$$

Which, when evaluated in the integral, gives:

$$\iiint_B x\ dx\,dy\,dz=\frac {8\pi}{3}$$

I understand that since the results are different, these domains are not equivalent. Moreover, since I know the right answer for this problem, I know that the second domain is wrong. But I can not understand why. Solving the integral is relatively easy, but finding the domain is not always very clear to me.

Why is the first domain $D$ right and the second domain $B$ is wrong in this case?

What is the Connection between $B$ & $D$ ?

Comment: @Cironis your comment is not appropriate.

Comment: @Cironis What a horrifyingly elitist comment. Is it hard to comprehend that people find different things difficult? You've answered no questions on the site, so what are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: That is ok. I am used to this kind of treatment to my questions. There is always a good soul that helps me in the end..

Comment: To @user3347814: $D$ is limited by $x=4y^2+4z^2$ and $x=4$?

Comment: Have you tried checking out the domain restriction equations on some 3d graphing software? Like geogebra3d. For me it helps a lot to visualize the problem at hand generally. You can plug in both domain restriction equations and the integral you want to integrate. This is not good for practice though, as the dimensionality of the integral can be easily increased in some questions.

Comment: You can see that the 2nd domain you propose is actually a cylinder of radius 1 and height $4r^2$, while the space enclosed by the constraints is not actually a cylinder. It is more like a cylinder with radius that increase with the value of $x$, exactly as your first choice of domain

Comment: The surface $x=4y^4+4z^4$ in polar form is not equal to $x=4r^2$. Also, $x$ is bounded *below* by $4y^4+4z^4$ and *above* by $4$, so your inequality should be $$4y^4+4z^4<x<4$$

Comment: FYI "integral domain" doesn't mean what you think it means; the tag is inappropriate

Comment: Please, use proper MathJax. Type `x^4` to get $x^4$ instead of unusual characters that are not properly render in many devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer by user AHusain is right , OP is going to get the Complements.

Here , I will give a visual way to see that Issue & then give the way to get it right.

In this Image , I am using arbitrary Curve , which is the Straight line in OP Case.

[image: 23 INTEGRAL]

Let the $Z$ Dimension be ignored here. It will come in , when $\theta$ varies. When $\theta=0$ , we will get the Area in the $XY$ Plane.
In the $XY$ Plane , $y$ & $r$ are Same.

**(A) Original Order :** When we let $x$ vary between $0$ & $4$ , then let $y=r$ vary between $0$ & $\sqrt{x/4}$ , we will rightly get the Area **below** the curve in the $XY$ Plane , where we are using the vertical green lines.

**(B) Changing the order Wrongly :** When we let $y=r$ vary between $0$ & $1$ , then let $x$ vary between $0$ & $4y^2=4r^2$ , we are using the horizontal green Solid lines in the Image.
That is the Area **above** the Curve !
In other words , "(B) + (A) = total rectangle" in $XY$ Plane.
In general , that "total rectangle" will be between the bottom-left corner limits & the top-right corner limits.

**(C) Changing the order Correctly :** When we let $y=r$ vary between $0$ & $1$ , then let $x$ vary between $4y^2=4r^2$ & $1$ , we are using the horizontal green Dotted lines in the Image.
That is the Area **below** the Curve.
In other words , "(C) = (A)" in $XY$ Plane.
When we Integrate with those Correct limits , we will get Consistent Answer.

This Analysis is valid for arbitrary Curve , though OP Case has the Straight line.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming typo that the exponents are 2 on $y$ and $z$ not $4$. The rest of your question uses that as the bounds.

The $\theta$ variable is irrelevant so let's just fix it to $0$ in both $D$ and $B$.

For $D$ we have $0 \lt r \lt \sqrt{\frac{x}{4}}$ and $0 \lt x \lt 4$, so we can consider $x=1$, $0 < r \lt \frac{1}{2}$.

Meanwhile, lets fix the same value of $x$ in $B$, we get the constraint $4r^2 \gt 1$, which means $1 \gt r \gt \frac{1}{2}$ when combined with the $0 \lt r \lt 1$.

It's the wrong way around. D and B are (interiors of) complements of each other inside the cylinder of height 4.

Add up the answers you get for D and B and you get $\frac{24\pi}{3} = 8 \pi$. Let $D+B$ be that cylinder

$$
I_{D+B} \equiv \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^4 x \; r \; dx \; dr \; d\theta\\
= 2 \pi \int_0^1 \int_0^4 x \; r \; dx \; dr\\
= 2 \pi \int_0^1 r \; 8 \; dr\\
= 16 \pi \int_0^1 r dr\\
= 8 \pi\\
I_{D+B} = I_D + I_B
$$

Comment: +1 , this is the right thinking. I was going to Post this , but you got it earlier. I might Post my own Answer , with a little more Detail ....